# Focus on first input after row is cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I'm pretty sure that I'm doing everything right, but I'm probably missing an event somewhere or something.

Here's what I've got. I have a table and it is filled with a row of inputs, just one row to start. There are four columns and on the fourth column of each row I have attached the `focusout` event. On `focusout` clone the last row and add a new row, with the first input of the new row being the focus so that they can just tab and continue.

What is not happening is that the first input is not getting the focus. So I'm trying to figure out why this is occurring.

I have a link to the fiddle and my code is below. Thank you for any help ahead of time!

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    var $lastRow = $('#testTable').find('tr:last');
    var $tbody = $('#textTabl').find('tbody');
    var $lastCell = $('#testTable').find('tr:last').find('td:last').prev().find('input');
    $($lastRow).find("td:first > input").focus();
    $('body').on('focusout',$lastCell,function(){
        var $newRow = $($lastRow).clone(true, true);
        $($lastRow).addClass('last');
        $($newRow).insertAfter($lastRow);
        $lastRow = $('#testTable').find('tr:last');
        $($lastRow).find("td:first > input").focus();
    });
});
```

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/dh0kxtLv/1/

**EDITS & UPDATES**

Currently using the new code above to experiment in my fiddle, but it's creating an odd behavior where the only cell that gets the focus is the first one, and if I try to focus out it duplicates the row and focuses on the next first cell. So it's kind of working but still failing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem you are experiencing is that the last cell is the last focusable element within the document. So by the time the focusout event is fired, focus has left the document which would remove your ability to focus any element.

Using your original code, simply adding an invisible focusable element below your table would avoid the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/dh0kxtLv/6/

Note the inclusion of `<div tabindex='0'></div>` after the table.

Comment: But the order of tabbable elements is incremental, 1 comes after 0, isn't it?!

Comment: Now, i'm really confused: http://jsfiddle.net/ud9ycqdt/1 **&** http://jsfiddle.net/70ug3ssd/  **&** http://jsfiddle.net/ud9ycqdt/2/ ?!

Comment: You are correct that tabindex is incremental, but consider 0 as a special case for defining that you want an element to receive focus based on it's order in the document.

Comment: You could think of tabindex as a priority rating, with 1 being the highest priority and zero being the least priority while still being able to be tabbed to.

Comment: Ya indeed, a special case regarding spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute   **If the value is a zero**  `The user agent must set the element's tabindex focus flag, should allow the element to be reached using sequential focus navigation, and should follow platform conventions to determine the element's relative order.`  Now i need to check what they mean by `platform conventions` ...

Answer (score 2):

To much code, just use:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('focusout','#testTable input:last',function(){
        var el=$(this);
        el.closest('tr').clone().insertAfter(el.closest('tr'))
        el.closest('table').find('tr:last input:first').focus();
    })
});
```

Comment: @Jack, you really don't need to use it in a VAR.

Comment: I'd set focusout on last TR element and check for `event.relatedTarget` in case user use `shift+tab` to navigate through the table and btw reset inputs value: http://jsfiddle.net/dh0kxtLv/12/

Comment: You created a global variable 'el', you should put the var back.

Comment: in this case is not global

Comment: @Vixed If you remove `var` statement, it is global

Comment: @A.Wolff with your fiddle the input will be cloned with a click everywhere.
I tested my code, it seems to work with shift+tab, without the relatedTarget. I've tested it on chrome.

Comment: @Jack you are right I've read it at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881415/when-is-the-var-need-in-js) sorry for the "battle" ;)

Comment: No problem!  Figured it was just a misunderstanding and that you'd try to verify it at some point.