# Need help javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know that in the following code, when  I reference an element 
by (document.getElementById) and make it equal to a variable for the validation purpose why I can't use the name instead of name1 in javascript.

```js
function validation() {
  name1 = document.getElementById('name');
  if (name1.value == "") {

    alert('this field cannot left empty');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="message.html" method="post" onSubmit='return validation()' />
<input type="text" placeholder="enter your name" id='name' />
<input type="text" placeholder="address" id='address' />
<input type="tel" placeholder="telephone" id="telephone" />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: Try using console... F12

Comment: are you saying you can't use `name=document.getElementById('name');` ?

Comment: Yes in this situation I can't use the variable name same like element id.

Comment: use `var name=document.getElementById('name');`

Comment: @Ali Raza first you need to add `var` before name1.

Comment: My question is that why  var name=document.getElementById('name'); this can't work.

Comment: This works man! Try it and let us know..

Comment: And in javascript you don't need to specify a variable if you don't put var before a variable name javascript will still use it as a variable.

Comment: @AliRaza I guess this stackoverflow question should answer your doubts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881415/when-is-the-var-need-in-js

Comment: Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var the reasons for declaring variables with var: variables declarations get creation priority over undeclared variables, undeclared variables are always global, undeclared variables may be deleted. In sum, to avoid potential problems it is usually better to declare variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding `var` to `name1` the code will start executing. After adding var you can assign the `document.getElementById('name')` to `name` also and it would work. You can run the below snippet for reference.

```js
function validation(){
    var name=document.getElementById('name');
    if(name.value== ""){
        alert('this field cannot left empty');
        return false;
     }
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="message.html" method="post"
 onSubmit='return validation()'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name" id='name' />
    <input type="text" placeholder="address" id='address' />
    <input type="tel" placeholder="telephone" id="telephone" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You need to place the `input`-elements inside the `form`-tag. `<form><input/><input/></form>`

Comment: One more issue in the code: `<form id="form" action="message.html" method="post"
 onSubmit='return validation()' />` must be `>` on the end.

Comment: Face palm. This is why copy paste doesn't work at times

Answer (score 0):

Try using this..

You forgot to `declare` the variable.
If you are using a `variable` for `assignment` you `must declare it` before using.

For more reference you can look up this popular thread in SO, [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it)

```
function validation(){
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    if(name.value== ""){
        alert('this field cannot left empty');
    return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a ton so it is always good to declare the variable . I thought that if i don't declare the variable javascript will still use it as a variable .

Comment: @AliRaza For clarifications regarding `var` you can consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it. It's always good practice to declare a variable before using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name=document.getElementById('name');
```

You should use var before an element name.